# What's the most simple way to get files only visible in Finder in a directory?

Tags: directory, finder, file-listing

NSFileManager has several method to enumerate directory contents, but they returns all files including hidden or system files which is invisible for users in Finder.

I want to get the file list same as Finder. As possible as simple. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Test the filename, usually a hidden file begins with a "." (period).

Comment: Thanks. But I heard there are some other conditions (not only names) which hide files from Finder. I just equal result with the Finder does. Is there no API for this?